# Libre Office Writer - how to add text to an image

Tags: libreoffice

I want to add text to an image which I have imported in Writer.

In Impress, I could insert a text field and move it to the place where I like to have the text. Is there a similar function in Writer or another way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Background Image

1. Insert image
   Left click on "Insert" menu, and click on "Image". From the file selection window select an image.
2. Format image
   Right click on the image, left click on "Format Image", In LO 5.4.1.2 click on "Properties..."
   In the [Wrap tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYUuF.png) select "Through", and check "In background".

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSByt.jpg) in any text/text box being printed over the background image.

### Text Box

Insert text box
    Left click on "Insert" menu, and click on "Text Box". Using the mouse left click and drag to create a text box, type text into the box. The color of the text may need to be changed for visibility.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately, neither works for me. In both cases, I can put the text before the image, to the left or to the right of the image or below the image but not over it. I'm using LibreOffice 5.2.6.2 and Windows 10.

Comment: @Marc: The Text Box solution worked for me (LO 5.4.0.3 on Win 10).  If the image is dark, then make sure it shows up by changing text color to white or making text very large, for example 72pt.  If the text box is truly behind the image, you could right-click on the image and select Arrange -> Send to Back.

Comment: @J. Starnes: Steps are clear, but perhaps it would help to include a screen capture.

Comment: I tried again with a bit more time and now both solutions work. I don't know why they didn't work the last time. Great, very easy to use. Thanks again J. Starnes and also thanks to Jim K.